# Jenkins: Add datetime column in history of test

Tags: jenkins

I would like to see the datetime the test run in the history output of jenkins.

[image]

I painted the area where I would like to see the datetime of the test run.

Up to now I found no way to configure this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in Jenkin's issue tracker, [JENKINS-7844](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7844):

> **A Filter to sort jobs by last run time.**
>   There are sort options for:
>   S W Job Last Success Last Failure ↓   Last Duration
>
> Please add one for Last Ran.
>
> Useful for seeing what has run in the last couple of hours/days (especially when there is a major build failure).

The issue was created October 2010, and was closed October 31st 2014 with "Status: Resolved" and this comment:

> Compact Columns solves this issue

So: check out [the Compact Columns plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Compact+Columns). Check "How do I use it?" section. It includes steps to add column in a view.

Comment: I think the plugin improves a different view.

Comment: I think plugin is provided to add for different views. Check "How do I use it?" section. It includes steps to add column in a view. @guettli